# Align Numeric Values from knitr command \Sexpr{} by Decimal in Table

Tags: r, knitr

How can I align numeric values brought in from the `knitr` command `\Sexpr{}` by decimal in a table?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why wouldn't you use `xtable` or `Hmisc` to create the entire table in R?

Comment: Probably because of other bad habits. I need to include graphics and text as well as the R calculations in a table. I'm using knitr since my GRA position would otherwise have me copy and paste lots of output into a working document, piece-by-piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `dcolumn` package. It allows defining a column that is centered at the decimal point. For example:

```
\begin{tabular}{D{.}{.}{3}}
    \Sexpr{1/4} \\
    \Sexpr{1/8} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Does this work for you? See the package's documentation for further options.

Add the `\usepackage{dcolumn}` command so that it appears in the preamble of the knitr-generated LaTeX file.

Comment: This is much simpler than hacking it up in the code chunk and recalling the individual pieces!

Comment: This work well with numeric values, but not numeric values in math mode.

Comment: @Chernoff: Might be due to "... that dcolumn always uses math mode for the digits as well as the separator." Does it work if you surround the `\Sexpr`s by `$` characters, to cancel the math mode that is created by `\Sexpr`? (See http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg27407.html for using a similar trick in a similar context but an entirely different environment.)

Comment: Values from `\Sexpr` line as expected in the table, but fail to do so when bracketed by `$`s.

Comment: @Chernoff: Then I don't understand your comment "This work well with numeric values, but not numeric values in math mode." Could you provide an example?

Comment: No, you're right. It just took as sec for it to sink in. `dcolumn` by default puts what's in the column into math mode. I no longer have to specify this. Surrounding the value with `$`s undoes the math mode.